# Is it allowed to ask questions politely to the imam during his preach?

Tags: practical-islam, muslim-practices, jumuah

I've wondered a long time but never took my courage in both hands to ask a question. And then I just left with my questions and ask them to other muslims who couldn't give me a sufficient answer.

So this is why I asked myself if it is allowed to ask questions to the imam during his preach but in a polite manner?

PS: I could go after the jumuah and try to find him if he hadn't already left.

Comment: Are you referring to only jumaah only  ? Are you referring to interrupt him in order to ask him?

Comment: Yeah, I'm just referring to the simple fact that I want to ask him a question about the content of his preach.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[It was narrated from Abu Hurairah that:](https://sunnah.com/nasai/19/22)

> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "If you say to your companion: 'Be
>   quiet and listen' when the imam is delivering the **Khutbah**, you have
>   engaged in idle speech."

Means it is not allowed to speak during Khutba, even to ask some one to be silent.

In any other speech, you can raise your hand and when Imam indicate, you can ask your question.

Comment: That's what I meant with "politely" asking the imam. Thank you for the hadeeth. جزاكم الله خيرا

Comment: In fact there's a sahih hadith showing that the prophet interrupted his khotbah to explain an issue to a questioner.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Any hadith regarding it would be much appreciated, without proof, it is meaningless.

Comment: Here are some references:  in [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/15/9) and also [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/11/56) there's also a hadith in Munsad Ahmad saying that somebody asked the prophet pbuh during his sermon "When would the Hour (Doomsday) take place?"  and the prophet pbuh came down and spoke to him this should also be quoted by ibn Qudamah in his al-Mughni. The point is how scholars qualify these incidences and what the correct practice is. And beside this the hadith you displayed says you may not speak to other listeners but doesn't exclude the imam.

Comment: In fact about the hadith you stated my own experience is that in Hanafi mosques (all Turkish mosques I visited in Germany so far) and a lot of Moslems from the middle east don't care to speak while the Imam is holding his sermon. In the Maghreb states people are reminded of this hadith before the prayer and it is considered as a no go to speak during the sermon. I found the above evidences while trying to check whether there actually is a difference in interpretation of this hadith among madhhabs. But there isn't so the above sketched is only "Muslim" practice.